# Shared Date Dimension

Tags: ssas

I have a date dimension that has identical attributes in several cubes.

How should I set this up

1. Have the dimension repeated in each cube
2. Make it a linked dimension from one cube to all the other cubes
3. Make a stand alone cube with just the date dimension and then have all the other cubes    link to that one instance
4. Something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cubes are in the same database, you should just be able to add the dimension to each one. Do you have a single database holding all the cubes, or do they live in different databases?

Comment: @WOPR, it's not right or wrong, depends on architecture/size/processing requirements. If the cubes are in different databases, I'd go for option 1 - Linked dimensions can have lower performance than regular dimensions.